# FaceAlpha is not allowed in errorbarseries

Tags: matlab, graph

I'm trying to set transparency on a error bar graph, but it seams that `facealpha`, `edgealpha` and others doesn't like to Matlab.
I tried with this two codes

`h1=errorbar(x,y1,e1,'facealpha', 0.3);`

`h1=errorbar(x,y1,e1,'facealpha', 0.3);
    set(h1,'FaceAlpha',0.3);`

```
x=[0.5
0.599
0.698
0.797
0.896
0.995
1.094
1.193
1.292
1.391
1.49
1.589
1.688
1.787
1.886
1.985
2.084
2.183
2.282
2.381
2.48
2.579
2.678
2.777
2.876
2.975
3.074
3.173
3.272
3.371
3.47
3.569
3.668
3.767
3.866
3.965
4.064
4.163
4.262
4.361
4.46
4.559
4.658
4.757
4.856
4.955
5.054
5.153
5.252
5.351
5.45
5.549
5.648
5.747
5.846
5.945
6.044
6.143
6.242
6.341
6.44
6.539
6.638
6.737
6.836
6.935
7.034
7.133
7.232
7.331
7.43
7.529
7.628
7.727
7.826
7.925
8.024
8.123
8.222
8.321
8.42
8.519
8.618
8.717
8.816
8.915
9.014
9.113
9.212
9.311
9.41
9.509
9.608
9.707
9.806
9.905
10.004
10.103
10.202
10.301
10.4
10.499
10.598
10.697
10.796
10.895
10.994
11.093
11.192
11.291
11.39
11.489
11.588
11.687
11.786
11.885
11.984
12.083
12.182
12.281
12.38
12.479
12.578
12.677
12.776
12.875
12.974
13.073
13.172
13.271
13.37
13.469
13.568
13.667
13.766
13.865
13.964
14.063
14.162
14.261
14.36
14.459
14.558
14.657
14.756
14.855
14.954
15.053
15.152
15.251
15.35
15.449
15.548
15.647
15.746
15.845
15.944
16.043
16.142
16.241
16.34
16.439
16.538
16.637
16.736
16.835
16.934
17.033
17.132
17.231
17.33
17.429
17.528
17.627
17.726
17.825
17.924
18.023
18.122
18.221
18.32
18.419
18.518
18.617
18.716
18.815
18.914
19.013
19.112
19.211
19.31
19.409
19.508
19.607
19.706
19.805
19.904
20.003
20.102
20.201
20.3
20.399
20.498
20.597
20.696
20.795
20.894
20.993
21.092
21.191
21.29
21.389
21.488
21.587
21.686
21.785
21.884
21.983
22.082
22.181
22.28
22.379
22.478
22.577
22.676
22.775
22.874
22.973
23.072
23.171
23.27
23.369
23.468
23.567
23.666
23.765
23.864
23.963
24.062
24.161
24.26
24.359
24.458
24.557
24.656
24.755
24.854
24.953
25.052
25.151
25.25
25.349
25.448
25.547
25.646
25.745
25.844
25.943
26.042
26.141
26.24
26.339
26.438
26.537
26.636
26.735
26.834
26.933
27.032
27.131
27.23
27.329
27.428
27.527
27.626
27.725
27.824
27.923
28.022
28.121
28.22
28.319
28.418
28.517
28.616
28.715
28.814
28.913
29.012
29.111
29.21
29.309
29.408
29.507
29.606
29.705
29.804
29.903
30.002
30.101
30.2
30.299
30.398
30.497
30.596
30.695
30.794
30.893
30.992
31.091
31.19
31.289
31.388
31.487
31.586
31.685
31.784
31.883
31.982
32.081
32.18
32.279
32.378
32.477
32.576
32.675
32.774
32.873
32.972
33.071
33.17
33.269
33.368
33.467
33.566
33.665
33.764
33.863
33.962
34.061
34.16
34.259
34.358
34.457
34.556
34.655
34.754
34.853
34.952
35.051
35.15
35.249
35.348
35.447
35.546
35.645
35.744
35.843
35.942
36.041
36.14
36.239
36.338
36.437
36.536
36.635
36.734
36.833
36.932
37.031
37.13
37.229
37.328
37.427
37.526
37.625
37.724
37.823
37.922
38.021
38.12
38.219
38.318
38.417
38.516
38.615
38.714
38.813
38.912
39.011
39.11
39.209
39.308
39.407
39.506
39.605
39.704
39.803
39.902
40.001
40.1
40.199
40.298
40.397
40.496
40.595
40.694
40.793
40.892
40.991
41.09
41.189
41.288
41.387
41.486
41.585
41.684
41.783
41.882
41.981
42.08
42.179
42.278
42.377
42.476
42.575
42.674
42.773
42.872
42.971
43.07
43.169
43.268
43.367
43.466
43.565
43.664
43.763
43.862
43.961
44.06
44.159
44.258
44.357
44.456
44.555
44.654
44.753
44.852
44.951
45.05
45.149
45.248
45.347
45.446
45.545
45.644
45.743
45.842
45.941
46.04
46.139
46.238
46.337
46.436
46.535
46.634
46.733
46.832
46.931
47.03
47.129
47.228
47.327
47.426
47.525
47.624
47.723
47.822
47.921
48.02
48.119
48.218
48.317
48.416
48.515
48.614
48.713
48.812
48.911
49.01
49.109
49.208
49.307
49.406
49.505
49.604
49.703
49.802
49.901
50
];
y1=[58.91379111
58.30406889
57.86655778
57.44249111
57.07903778
56.82827111
56.56522444
56.27355556
56.10313556
55.87803333
55.65315556
55.46745333
55.27182667
55.10819111
54.92536667
54.75653556
54.55088
54.37453778
54.19983333
54.02070222
53.85127556
53.67266889
53.49395778
53.32762667
53.17425111
53.00737333
52.86911778
52.78734889
52.63589556
52.52291333
52.40382
52.23062
52.07598444
51.90439556
51.71540444
51.49068667
51.35339778
51.2269
50.99248222
50.82302
50.58865556
50.40766889
50.25531778
50.16989556
50.11199556
50.01857556
49.84359556
49.76161333
49.56494444
49.36535111
49.25795778
49.05989556
48.90024222
48.6367
48.3922
48.22511778
47.99941556
47.74950222
47.64634667
47.49712444
47.38079556
47.26710889
47.02807778
46.84877333
46.67821333
46.48263333
46.38094889
46.32203333
46.05293778
45.83451333
45.68522222
45.46053333
45.32688222
45.25344667
45.02278889
44.78054444
44.67167778
44.52148444
44.35262444
44.28865111
44.15980889
43.93043556
43.80913556
43.73212222
43.45288
43.36568889
43.11002222
42.83706444
42.71576
42.61057333
42.38485556
42.31693333
42.08588444
41.79026
41.65217556
41.65218889
41.54988444
41.37677111
41.34832444
41.01547333
40.89681111
40.8126
40.58801111
40.46189556
40.20469556
39.86633556
39.75806889
39.73943111
39.52372667
39.35357778
39.21645333
38.99232444
38.85530667
38.71794667
38.77353778
38.45291333
38.26666222
38.12013111
38.04776889
38.14514444
38.00924444
37.61260222
37.37561556
37.13516667
36.98286444
36.85687333
36.72820222
36.49741556
36.23045111
36.22308667
36.16983778
36.21561111
36.18526444
35.93888
35.54634667
35.46280889
35.39300889
35.18587111
35.06764
34.87271556
34.57579111
34.45287556
34.35492667
34.19111333
34.18776667
33.97069333
33.73575111
33.65990222
33.69544
33.59749778
33.58598889
33.27395778
33.11072444
33.11043111
33.10660667
32.88859111
32.71438
32.47852222
32.13379333
32.05672667
31.92117778
31.79712667
31.60673778
31.49441333
31.35479778
31.46140889
31.45518222
31.54568444
31.35947556
31.04802444
30.83647556
30.87881333
30.74116
30.40970889
30.0038
29.85696667
29.76281556
29.84990667
29.77114222
29.62808
29.60895333
29.27633778
29.12867111
29.15629111
29.13050444
29.02321556
28.94240667
28.74771556
28.70833111
28.65075556
28.39046222
28.19522667
28.08066
27.91423778
27.70231333
27.64870889
27.53530222
27.35607333
27.44800444
27.43877111
27.48427111
27.59587333
27.46848444
27.10720444
27.00811333
26.64861111
26.59074222
26.72312
26.6829
26.34899111
26.37787778
26.20782
26.05105333
25.93752222
25.83426889
25.60743111
25.77854444
25.83389111
25.96624222
26.3375
26.48426222
25.96040222
25.53307778
25.30371778
25.05830667
24.81032889
24.48608444
24.26347778
24.29737333
24.54590444
24.46596222
24.54412444
24.39605556
24.24244
24.17091111
24.21673111
24.20671333
24.13121111
24.12353778
23.90133333
23.84444
23.84672222
23.60599333
23.42314444
23.13092667
22.97691333
22.94989111
23.03685556
22.96116
23.06216889
23.1557
23.09719111
23.15541333
23.12103556
23.18801111
23.16691778
22.91112
22.63339556
22.29862
22.16606667
22.00156444
21.82672444
21.73648444
21.50631556
21.57598222
21.69250667
21.73508667
21.85469333
21.97531778
21.91353556
21.99895556
22.04597333
21.88391778
21.70434667
21.24216222
20.88416222
20.80748444
20.85568889
20.92855778
20.65875333
20.64993111
20.67923333
20.55427556
20.67756667
20.56815111
20.54210889
20.81350889
20.77248444
20.69868667
20.83035333
20.67720444
20.39263778
20.04227333
19.67798444
19.39141556
19.24020222
19.19796
19.23772
19.36842444
19.47069333
19.55001111
19.71582667
19.8777
19.70428444
19.77787778
19.77551333
19.40041111
19.45821111
19.55338444
19.47475333
19.12444444
18.79559111
18.48484444
18.40952667
18.50604
18.53192222
18.63778444
18.76984667
18.75701333
19.08353556
19.42952889
19.44785556
19.18290444
18.84869333
18.71425556
18.58470889
18.16851333
18.12542
18.15658889
17.79132444
17.66769778
17.57606889
17.39153778
17.51415778
17.46347556
17.69762
17.69535556
18.01982889
18.23046667
18.61870667
18.89263778
18.62632889
18.05526222
17.19354667
16.90540889
16.74351778
16.56405778
16.77144889
16.78889333
16.78826889
16.88390889
17.07516
17.15444889
17.12606444
17.04842667
17.17401556
17.79134
17.4739
17.58559333
17.58906222
17.07684222
16.78251333
16.75757778
15.93561111
15.46106444
15.39324889
15.47948222
15.47859111
16.15476222
16.44297556
16.87588
17.59446889
16.84612889
16.77234667
16.24222889
16.12268889
15.85323778
15.80468667
15.80785778
15.66301111
15.83960222
15.68031111
15.4616
15.56739778
15.45226
15.05107333
14.97228
15.17434889
15.55644
15.77411333
16.06133111
16.14503333
16.76523778
17.07217778
15.68344
14.96925333
14.54249556
14.11624667
14.26320667
14.39059333
14.3727
14.4196
14.92078889
15.23729778
15.33467111
15.72018222
15.52989556
15.80589556
15.68176444
15.61869111
15.06168667
14.34414444
14.07653111
14.12861778
14.29020222
14.08007778
13.83600667
14.04506222
14.25244667
14.30486667
14.53562667
14.59949556
14.59716889
14.80515111
14.80747556
15.06598
14.80876222
14.58690444
14.83936222
14.62647111
14.14737556
13.77610222
13.39399778
12.98910444
13.10684889
12.84773556
13.25049333
13.59834667
14.15359333
14.63882889
15.00409111
15.47089556
15.40962889
14.04486889
13.32282222
13.61366667
13.07759111
13.06812
12.73542889
12.90276444
12.68617333
13.27119111
13.46084889
13.54924222
13.71445778
13.80004
13.56251333
13.19737333
13.44442667
13.45793778
13.81111333
14.07576667
14.07479778
13.17868
12.98209556
12.39020444
12.15059778
12.30663556
12.47023111
12.98838222
12.44017778
13.05068444
13.12750889
13.16898222
12.96968222
13.25138444
13.71496222
13.20418667
13.29648222
13.39754667
12.90556
12.06877333
11.99710889
12.00332444
12.08596444
12.06618222
11.82721333
12.48592667
12.68958
12.73576667
13.22932889
13.45741556
13.41520444
13.0949
12.25921333
11.86815333
11.54043556
11.66715778
12.30690889
12.48060222
12.61462889
];
e1=[
    1.778469436
1.769647558
1.766976334
1.755049866
1.747236293
1.746139458
1.74881832
1.738667931
1.733259101
1.735286985
1.735294388
1.730839313
1.72755607
1.730313588
1.727085914
1.723699181
1.722510431
1.723712171
1.721674936
1.71629688
1.715269249
1.716058671
1.711038989
1.704656588
1.702852394
1.703441514
1.698703045
1.691218279
1.692111317
1.691358752
1.682763262
1.68124008
1.682252337
1.679545562
1.676298813
1.67705236
1.676224896
1.672200561
1.665208579
1.663727865
1.662025359
1.656142255
1.650174384
1.647755171
1.643878711
1.633956371
1.628822171
1.627094421
1.624059053
1.620403637
1.616763823
1.614599298
1.610683002
1.601937783
1.597218865
1.594465352
1.588501877
1.581758594
1.579353265
1.577014371
1.568598983
1.562789278
1.55655013
1.551457403
1.547143767
1.543618194
1.537921723
1.535884075
1.528973474
1.521884762
1.517734322
1.515849562
1.510995308
1.505472161
1.499248436
1.49152235
1.484582328
1.477607078
1.469664231
1.463722052
1.463315857
1.457632379
1.452614183
1.449566044
1.441810345
1.433246245
1.428419199
1.424914238
1.420023099
1.416791361
1.410765001
1.40251888
1.395698893
1.388741413
1.383876209
1.382214906
1.378000476
1.367349342
1.361925497
1.354342044
1.345838121
1.341310582
1.340692983
1.338309967
1.331373762
1.325821511
1.320191338
1.312718287
1.303192922
1.296156082
1.295029771
1.29400209
1.28523024
1.275873885
1.270279417
1.260840675
1.253025025
1.248690879
1.248335249
1.248551683
1.243942457
1.233739089
1.223879169
1.220497844
1.216335314
1.209777439
1.205498476
1.197800109
1.1907033
1.18069059
1.174690626
1.170028045
1.168592124
1.167261712
1.163705744
1.161608877
1.158208923
1.147918463
1.137800209
1.134072434
1.130481024
1.12687384
1.124764745
1.119226441
1.113681573
1.101433162
1.093302487
1.087615421
1.083389721
1.082350059
1.077428884
1.068679317
1.06098089
1.056984539
1.055722669
1.051956392
1.046612445
1.044453941
1.039932033
1.033487779
1.024572495
1.016033598
1.010174758
1.007647021
1.006719585
1.003486743
0.99931611
0.99534938
0.98683714
0.978203723
0.972751769
0.976704233
0.978031977
0.968532802
0.958546421
0.956888001
0.957264159
0.951606963
0.943003838
0.939979787
0.936159232
0.926615109
0.915006066
0.908236589
0.903678565
0.899547649
0.899242424
0.901277221
0.904942561
0.903487646
0.893447575
0.886591786
0.883563655
0.878324094
0.871472571
0.866476004
0.864046491
0.857763908
0.851830474
0.849543773
0.848185848
0.847615402
0.846024355
0.839014747
0.832898872
0.826950988
0.817973405
0.81553702
0.820208584
0.817236728
0.82119052
0.824877601
0.82156277
0.808804371
0.795321957
0.786442944
0.778040353
0.774269926
0.778601311
0.801815855
0.817186002
0.788894215
0.776162104
0.780274036
0.791367845
0.787482769
0.772643017
0.76185894
0.744843869
0.738115835
0.731549343
0.734044959
0.74037331
0.744434828
0.745006525
0.743489034
0.729719677
0.71764489
0.710909354
0.71093011
0.715676107
0.723736179
0.720466835
0.718463704
0.713534232
0.711672502
0.71050903
0.703665821
0.692202103
0.683857998
0.685844447
0.678619309
0.672740333
0.67311948
0.684235604
0.696315878
0.693140812
0.690473186
0.680228288
0.667553023
0.657622997
0.653617861
0.652369663
0.64831128
0.647069556
0.646576372
0.643434056
0.638551954
0.635148636
0.632447796
0.642252389
0.653366757
0.651857588
0.646383787
0.623243778
0.61795417
0.618180805
0.623485941
0.624656476
0.626813261
0.619214997
0.611237903
0.598288496
0.590185358
0.584512713
0.581659524
0.596136038
0.600488639
0.609321406
0.616190081
0.605768331
0.596846371
0.598750305
0.600947871
0.607904074
0.599345022
0.590716768
0.576203361
0.563462084
0.555775057
0.557025497
0.564050244
0.576514275
0.589247713
0.589687515
0.575134728
0.556329335
0.557000561
0.573073658
0.579275515
0.56244252
0.557810696
0.552033523
0.549833075
0.539682512
0.532569527
0.525667629
0.524665217
0.53189283
0.551984945
0.591895952
0.587804325
0.554383944
0.537342536
0.535519441
0.541669938
0.5218078
0.522116821
0.519052604
0.510846307
0.50792427
0.516978859
0.516321288
0.50645667
0.503346972
0.51166763
0.496832848
0.49470271
0.5006172
0.552252867
0.608196052
0.602037391
0.564012428
0.499915037
0.496924284
0.497507097
0.502888422
0.495130466
0.488085916
0.494367263
0.492003958
0.484438445
0.477306779
0.473454673
0.475538466
0.481235081
0.568506804
0.55834616
0.565580855
0.541494267
0.484205184
0.483334243
0.524201147
0.498761481
0.509368296
0.496356166
0.485726804
0.457995622
0.432837734
0.436761202
0.490556759
0.639714856
0.580394868
0.570172504
0.47230109
0.448274132
0.44757304
0.451423944
0.445220643
0.46740233
0.512628766
0.489885728
0.446357965
0.442074195
0.460501588
0.471120671
0.45655822
0.458116907
0.480474755
0.47664076
0.445432637
0.451601033
0.557531383
0.664011842
0.482104001
0.47168489
0.491809015
0.489675329
0.464600854
0.454173499
0.42139502
0.410887958
0.471441246
0.529534685
0.476519463
0.455908078
0.431092461
0.47033774
0.478485896
0.560222598
0.539761188
0.495006983
0.44118316
0.395031388
0.403073402
0.410777645
0.423909983
0.440034773
0.478964325
0.452513077
0.411909754
0.39222199
0.387791228
0.416914403
0.478841218
0.585563846
0.548672266
0.470222694
0.443436135
0.425969826
0.425134003
0.438887625
0.43130752
0.45620409
0.461739591
0.424679926
0.382932203
0.356464435
0.361533196
0.475417366
0.610741158
0.677396319
0.783189373
0.450925807
0.372301695
0.394999731
0.386954026
0.379081853
0.434673868
0.460628178
0.449373214
0.399167187
0.37068818
0.372059522
0.382924258
0.439412623
0.505270733
0.492194329
0.464516941
0.401345763
0.37830721
0.442220507
0.472638784
0.448179707
0.52156545
0.529734813
0.480410391
0.384511577
0.334949355
0.337207383
0.355617404
0.550938378
0.638246046
0.565426926
0.450102043
0.355872068
0.393139076
0.375292353
0.472787886
0.722449357
0.787932133
0.578317585
0.398774606
0.353083755
0.393471458
0.399755139
0.441663788
0.589177455
0.604506533
0.478444066
0.404120334
0.409687115
0.477772283
0.518010185
0.500814888
0.629980792
0.582595527
0.426537229
0.344627741
0.351915846
0.355310533
];
color_red = [244 56 47] ./ 255;
figure;hold on;grid on;box on;legend on;
h1=errorbar(x,y1,e1);
set(h1,'FaceAlpha',0.3);
set(gca, 'Xlim', [0 50])
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Done. I didn't do that because are just useless code.

Comment: Your code is not Complete as we don't have values for `frequency`, `mean` and `devstd`. A [mcve] should at least provide the possibility for us to be working if we copy paste it in Matlab.

Comment: I added the values

Comment: How about using https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26311-shadederrorbar?

Comment: I'm using this too. But lines appears thinner than errorbar. I don't know if is just my eyes or is real.